# Intersection of an ellipsoid given by SPD matrix with axes

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Given a SPD matrix $\mathbf{A}$, for example

$\mathbf{A} = \pmatrix{ 5 & 4 \\ 4 & 5}$

defining an ellipsoid $\epsilon_\mathbf{A}$ with semiaxes length given by $\frac{1}{\lambda_i} \mathbf{v}_i$ i.e. the major semiaxis length is defined by the smallest eigenvalue-eigenvector pair, etc.,

how to find the ellipsoid intersections with coordinate axes, i.e. the points

$\mathbf{x} = (x_0, 0)$

and

$\mathbf{y} = (0, y_0)$?

Comment: If you only know matrix $A$, then your ellipse is centred at $(0,0)$ and its cartesian equation should be $$(x,y)A\pmatrix{x\\y}=1.$$ Substitute $(0,y)$ or $(x,0)$ into that equation and solve for the only remaining variable.

Comment: so the intersections are given just by inverse of square roots of the diagonal elements of A?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Just make a graph of your equation (with GeoGebra, or Desmos) to check.